# htaccess redirect begins with

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to add a simple .htaccess 301 redirect. urls like:

```
s.nl/sc/2.f?...
s.nl/it...
s.nl/?=...
```

I would like to match any url that starts with "s.nl".
What I've been trying is:

```
RewriteRule ^s\.nl/.*$ / [L,R=301]
```

Update: This is the final rule that worked correctly:

```
RewriteRule /s\.nl.*$ /? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you have is almost correct. In your RewriteRule it looks like you are trying to match the `/` after `s.nl`, if this is the case then the `/` has to be escaped (`\/`):

```
RewriteRule ^s\.nl\/ / [R=301]
```

The `L` flag is most likely not required, unless you have additional rules using `RewriteCond`.

If you want anything to be matched after `s.nl` then the `RewriteRule` is simply:

```
RewriteRule ^s\.nl / [R=301]
```

**nb**. if you want the drop the query string when redirecting you can add `?` to the redirect destination:

```
RewriteRule ^s\.nl.*$ /? [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you.  At first I could not get it to work, but when I changed it to:
    RewriteRule /s\.nl.*$ /? [R=301]

it worked.